# some uid's in /proc/pid/loginuid are strange

Tags: linux, unix, procfs

i'm analysing the procfs in unix/linux and some loginuid of processes are really strange. Some pid's have as loginuid a big number: 4294967295. Are they daemons or system events or whats the matter?

```
# cat /proc/11071/loginuid
4294967295
```

Comment: 4294967295 is the largest number possible as a 32-bit integer, not that it explains why you see loginuids

Comment: 1. Thats not the point

Comment: Inspecting some of those processes with 32bit int max loginuids on my own Fedora Linux machine, they are kernel processes `[kworker/u16:26]`

Comment: Here's something "_The audit daemon enables the audit facility in the kernel. Any process
    that runs before the auditing capability is turned on in the kernel will
    get loginuid 4294967295._" http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/audit-faq.txt

Comment: I don't know that auditd is the _only_ reason a process would get  loginuid 4294967295, but that's the one thing I found on it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

4294967295 is just (unsigned long) -1. -1 means that loginuid was not set. This is normal behavior for processes that were not spawned by any login process (e.g. for daemons).
loginuid is -1 by default; pam_loginuid module changes it to your user id whenever you login (in a tty/in DM/via ssh), and this value is preserved by child processes.

Answer (score 3):

I am gravedigging, but I stumped on this and I have infos to share.

1. kernel support

*loginuid* support required the kernel compiled with CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL

To check:

> zgrep CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL /boot/config* /proc/config.gz

2. kernel bugs

At the moment, I can check on two centos hosts.
Both of them have 64 bit kernels compiled with *CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL=y*

I am logged as a normal user in bash.

centos 5.11, kernel 2.6.18-419.el5

> cat /proc/$$/loginuid
>
> 4294967295

centos 6.10, kernel 2.6.32-754.28.1.el6

> cat /proc/$$/loginuid
>
> 503